# How can I verify that a swt text widget is a decimal value

Tags: java, text, swt, eclipse-rcp, decimal

In swt, text widget allow any string.
But What is the most appropriate SWT widget in which to enter a Decimal value?

I found two answers :

1. First, implement the VerifyKeyListener and VerifyListener, work for french decimal notation, but simple and easy to implement :

```java
package test.actions;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.eclipse.swt.custom.VerifyKeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.VerifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.VerifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public final class AmountVerifyKeyListener implements VerifyListener, VerifyKeyListener             {

    private static final String REGEX = "^[-+]?[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]{0,2}+$"; 

    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);  

    public void verifyText(VerifyEvent verifyevent) {
        verify(verifyevent);
    }

    public void verifyKey(VerifyEvent verifyevent) {
        verify(verifyevent);
    }

    private void verify (VerifyEvent e) {
        String string = e.text;
        char[] chars = new char[string.length()];
        string.getChars(0, chars.length, chars, 0);

        Text text = (Text)e.getSource();

        if ( ( ",".equals(string) || ".".equals(string) ) && text.getText().indexOf(',') >= 0 ) {
            e.doit = false;
            return;
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (!(('0' <= chars[i] && chars[i] <= '9') || chars[i] == '.' ||  chars[i] == ',' || chars[i] == '-')) {
                e.doit = false;
                return;
            } 


            if ( chars[i] == '.' ) {
                chars[i] = ',';
            }
        }

        e.text = new String(chars);

        final String oldS = text.getText();
        String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newS);
        if ( !matcher.matches() ) {
            e.doit = false;
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

And the main class associated to the verifyKeyListener :

```java
package test.actions;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);

        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
        text.addVerifyListener(new AmountVerifyKeyListener() ) ;

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

1. Use the FormattedText from the nebula project : http://eclipse.org/nebula/

Somebody see another solution ?

Comment: It's a shame that SWT does not have such important widgets available... i'm using Nebula for NUMBER formatting only (i wrote my DATE and TIME). I found it quite good, but i had to edit some bits of the code to make it work with cell editors and not to interfere with databinding.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner and easier way would be to use Double.parseString() and catch the NumberFormatException's to figure out if the text in it can be converted to a double.

Comment: Agree.. It's strange for me to see such a huge code for a simple number format check.

Comment: I'd rather use `BigDecimal` instead of `Double`, because of various reasons.

Comment: And about the local ? Double.parseString will be ok to parse string like : 
french notation : 1 234,567 
english notation : 1 234.567
other notation : 1234.567

Comment: A partial expression like "5." or "6E-" should be fine for the validation while typing but would not be fine for Double.parseDouble(expression);

Answer (score 0):

- For the validation of Double values you have to consider that characters like E may be included in Doubles and that partial input like "4e-" should be valid while typing to allow to finally enter "4e-3". The partial expressions might give a NumberFormatException for Double.parseDouble(partialExpression)
- Also see my answer at following related question: 
  [How to set a Mask to a SWT Text to only allow Decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831927/how-to-set-a-mask-to-a-swt-text-to-only-allow-decimals/)
- (Further note: If one only wants to allow Integer values a Spinner can be used instead of a text field.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple regex on the widget like the following:

```java
    if(Text.getText().matches("^[0-9]+$")) {
       show an error dialog or similar
    }
```