# SWT/JFace: How to set max textlength in TableViewerColumn

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I set the max number of characters to input in a JFace `TableViewerColumn`? Is there a way to get the contained control and cast it?

So, here's (almost) the complete class:

```
public class CustomerTab extends Composite implements ITableLabelProvider {
    org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout layout = null;

    Table table = null;

    GridData griddata = null;

    TableViewer viewer = null;

    private CustomerSearchFilter filter;

    public CustomerTab(Composite arg1, int arg2) throws SQLException {
        super(arg1, arg2);

        layout = new org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout(GridData.FILL_BOTH,
                false);
        layout.numColumns = 1;

        this.setLayout(layout);

        Button button = new Button(this, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("New customer");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(ApplicationRunner
                        .getApp().getShell(), new NewCustomerWizard());
                if (wizardDialog.open() == Window.OK) {
                    System.out.println("Ok pressed");
                    try {
                        viewer.setInput(CustomerDAO.getInstance().getAll());
                        viewer.refresh();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO something
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cancel pressed");
                }
            }
        });

        final Text searchText = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SEARCH);
        searchText.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL
                | GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL));

        addTable();

        // Support the search
        searchText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                filter.setSearchText(searchText.getText());
                viewer.refresh();
            }

        });
        filter = new CustomerSearchFilter();
        viewer.addFilter(filter);
    }

    public void addTable() throws SQLException {

        viewer = new TableViewer(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI
                | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

        final Table table = viewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        createColumns(this, viewer);

        viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        viewer.setInput(CustomerDAO.getInstance().getAll());

        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
    }

    private void createColumns(final Composite parent, final TableViewer viewer) {
        String[] titles = { "ID", "Firma", "Anrede", "Vorname", "Nachname",
                "Strasse", "Plz", "Ort", "Tel. privat", "Tel. gesch.", " " };
        int[] bounds = { 30, 130, 50, 100, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100, 100, 30 };



        // Col 1, ID
        TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                Customer p = (Customer) element;
                return String.valueOf(p.getId());
            }
        });
        col.setEditingSupport(new TestFirstNameEditingSupport(viewer));


        // other columns here...

        // Col 4, Firstname
        col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                Customer p = (Customer) element;
                return p.getFirstname();
            }
        });
        col.setEditingSupport(new TestFirstNameEditingSupport(viewer));

        // and the rest of the columns here

    }

    private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, int bound,
            final int colNumber) {
        final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer,
                SWT.NONE);
        final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
        column.setText(title);
        column.setWidth(bound);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(true);
        return viewerColumn;
    }

    // LabelProvider
    @Override
    public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLabelProperty(Object arg0, String arg1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public Image getColumnImage(Object arg0, int arg1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnText(Object arg0, int arg1) {

        String result = "";
        switch (arg1) {
        case 0:
            result = "ID";
            break;
        ...

        case 4:
            result = "Firstname";
            break;
        ...

        default:
            // should not get here
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    }

    static class TestFirstNameEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

        private final TableViewer viewer;
        private TextCellEditor editor = null;

        public TestFirstNameEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer) {
            super(viewer);
            this.viewer = viewer;
            editor = new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTable());

            Text text = (Text) editor.getControl();

            //  set maximal length HERE
            text.setTextLimit(3);
        }

        public CellEditor getMyCellEditor(Object element) {
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
            return new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTable());
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getValue(Object element) {
            return ((de.devision.data.bean.Customer) element).getVorname();
        }

        @Override
        protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {

            if (String.valueOf(value).length() <= 2 || String.valueOf(value).equals("")) {
                MessageDialog.openInformation(ApplicationRunner.getApp().getShell(), "to short!", "at least 3 characters!");
                return;
            }

            ((Customer) element).setVorname(String.valueOf(value));

            try {
                CustomerDAO.getInstance().update(((Customer) element));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO maybe later
            }
            viewer.refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally got it working:

```
private static void createViewer(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
    createColumns(parent, viewer);
    final Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    // Get the content for the viewer, setInput will call getElements in the
    // contentProvider
    viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getPersons());
    // Set the sorter for the table

    // Layout the viewer
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);

    comparator = new PersonViewerComparator();
    viewer.setComparator(comparator);
}

// This will create the columns for the table
private static void createColumns(final Composite parent,
        final TableViewer viewer) {
    String[] titles = { "First name", "Last name", "Gender", "Married" };
    int[] bounds = { 100, 100, 100, 100 };

    // First column is for the first name
    TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            Person p = (Person) element;
            return p.getFirstName();
        }
    });

    col.setEditingSupport(new CheckLengthEditingSupport(viewer)); 

    // Second column is for the last name
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            Person p = (Person) element;
            return p.getLastName();
        }
    });

    // Now the gender
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[2], bounds[2], 2);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            Person p = (Person) element;
            return p.getGender();
        }
    });

    // // Now the status married
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public Image getImage(Object element) {
            if (((Person) element).isMarried()) {
                return CHECKED;
            } else {
                return UNCHECKED;
            }
        }
    });
}

static class CheckLengthEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

    private final TableViewer viewer;
    private TextCellEditor editor = null;

    public FirstNameEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer);
        this.viewer = viewer;
        editor = new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTable());

        Text text = (Text) editor.getControl();

        //  set maximal length HERE
        text.setTextLimit(3);
    }

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        return ((YourObject) element).getName();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        ((YourObject) element).setName(String.valueOf(value));
        viewer.update(element, null);
    }
}
```

You have to set the `TextCellEditor` within the `EditingSupport` class and return it in the `protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element)` method.

BTW: If you want another restriction than "less than x characters", you can simply add a `VerifyListener` to the `text` in the `TextCellEditor`.

Comment: hm, actually, I'd like to limit the possibility of inputing character into the field. Equivalent to (Text)myField.setTextLimit(10); so, you cannot input more than n characters into the table field in the first place?

Comment: @MarcusToepper So your table is editable? If so, could you provide the code you use for this editing?

Comment: jip. I thought about putting it in the editingSupport (which works fine), but that would check only after the input, which is to late from my point of view.

Comment: @MarcusToepper Without the code, I cannot tell you how to do this. I managed to get something similar working on an SWT `Text` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831927/how-to-set-a-mask-to-a-swt-text-to-only-allow-decimals/11832021#11832021). This listener checks if the input is a decimal and rejects wrong input. Maybe you can use something similar (check if input is too long)?

Comment: *g* that's my problem, I don't know how to get the control from the tableviewercolumn and therefore can neither limit nor add something to it. I tried getting it via column.getInfo().getControl() or some like this, but that's not it.

Comment: @MarcusToepper Ok, I see. But how did you enable table-editing in place? It's not the default setting... If you can provide this code, I may be able to help you.

Comment: will give it a try, just afk for a moment

Comment: this keeps you from inputing more that the allowed number of characters?

Comment: @MarcusToepper Yes, it does. Added some of the remaining code, so you can compare.

Comment: I don't get it, I can't find any differences. Made the EditingSupport an inner class for testing. Post above contains now the whole class. If you'd have a look, that'd be great!

Comment: @MarcusToepper The method `protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element)` has to return the `TextCellEditor` you created in the constructor, not a new one. That should fix it...

Comment: did I mention your personal-hero-state before? ;) thanx!